# CRM 2013 - Prevent Deletion of a record based on a condition

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have an entity titled Document Access. Now, this entity Document Access has a N:1 relationship with Incident (One Incident can have many Document Access).

When someone creates a new Document Access record, I have a JS which checks if the person who is creating the record (current logged in user) is the same as the Incident's owner. If not, I disallow the creation (this is set on the Save of the record).

The Document Access record's owner can be anyone (not necessarily the Incident's owner). How can I ensure the prevention of the deletion of these Document Access records unless it is done by the Owner of the Incident?

1. Can I achieve it via Security Roles? I am not able to come up with a solution that can achieve this via Security Roles so that the Delete button does not even appear when a View or a Form is displayed.
2. Can I achieve the same via JavaScript hooking into the Delete button as part of
   the ribbon? If so, how can I get the Incident id that is being selected for Deletion? Would it also be triggered if we did a bulk delete?
3. If it is a plugin, should it be on the Pre-Validation stage of the Delete operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer and qualify each of your own options:

1. **Using Security Roles**.  No because you want to control the deletion based on the ownership of a related entity which isn't possible.
2. **Using JavaScript**.  You could hide the buttons with a custom JavaScript ribbon rule that compares the Incident owner to the Document Access record owner.  However, this approach won't support all use cases including bulk delete.
3. **Using a Plugin**.  This is the correct approach and registering on Pre-Validation is fine.  It will enforce your business rule regardless of where the delete request originates.  This could be from a user via the UI, a bulk delete or platform operation such as an external integration request.  Make sure you return a meaningful message in the exception that explains the business rule.

Answer (score 1):

The best approcah is to do this through a plugin on Delete of Document Access records.

In your code you may follow this steps:

1. Retrieve the Owner of the Incident related with the Document Access:

   `Guid incidentId --> You get this form the lookup field, you have in Document Access to Incident
   Entity incident = service.Retrive("incident", incidentId, new ColumnSet("onwerid"));`
2. Check if the user who triggered the plugin is the Owner of the Incident

   `// context --> execution plugin context
   Guid ownerIncident = ((EntityReference)incident.Attributes["ownerid"]).Id;
   if(ownerIncident != context.InitiatingUserId)
   {
     throw new InvalidPluginExecutionContext("Can't delete Documet Access record");
   } // otherwise let the record to be deleted`